# I can't flag as duplicated because it has no accepted answer

Tags: discussion, support, flags, duplicate-questions

A question has been asked a year ago with high score: [IE10 websocket Allow insecureFromHttps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627516/ie10-websocket-allowinsecurefromhttps)

Question "Possible duplicated" asked 6 months: [Can we allow unsecure websocekt (ws://) over https protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186496/can-we-allow-unsecure-websocekt-ws-over-https-protocol)

I flagged the second question as duplicated, I got this message:
[image]

Is flagging question as duplicated based on having answers Or based on Which Question has been asked first?

If (6 months ago) Question got accepted answer, will the (year ago)question be flagged as duplicated and maybe closed(**in my opinion it is not fair to close the older one**)?

Comment: If the newer post has an answer, feel free to close the *older* post as a duplicate of the newer one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I cant close questions, I can flag them, and I couldn't flag it even it is "possible duplicated".

Comment: You cannot flag the newer post as a dupe of the older, no. But you *can* flag them the other way around.

Comment: @gnat Yes it is duplicated I think.